# Cannot create unbalanced journal entry. Ids: Differences debit - credit Error when trying to create an invoice line

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to create an invoice line using the Web APIs and XML-RPC (python). I receive this error while creating it.

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 2: 'Cannot create unbalanced journal entry. Ids: [12083]\nDifferences debit - credit: [-2629.33]'>
```

I'm creating the invoice line as follows:

```py
inv_line_id = models.execute_kw(
        db, uid, password, 
       'account.move.line',
       'create'[
           {'move_id':invoice_id,
            'product_id':product_id[0]['id'],
            'price_unit':product_id[0]['list_price'],
            'quantity':sale_line_id[0]['product_uom_qty'],
            'account_id':account_id[0]['property_account_income_categ_id'][0]
            }
            ]
   )
```

If i dont add the 'price_unit' the invoice line is being created normally but without a price.

Anyone knows how to fix this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a pure business problem. Your code isn't wrong. But Invoice change with the time and it's really important to know your Odoo version

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the same version of me (V13) or if the code is the same in your version. You could pass a value in the context to don't check the balanced.

```
'check_move_validity' = False
```

Find in the file account/models/account_move.py . Line 1721 in method write

```
        # Ensure the move is still well balanced.
    if 'line_ids' in vals:
        if self._context.get('check_move_validity', True):
            self._check_balanced()
        self.update_lines_tax_exigibility()
```

Comment: Yes I just did that and it worked , not sure if it is a good approach though (since I'm new to Odoo). If it doesn't cause any issues I'll mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, this is not technical, it's only business logic.

Comment: how to pass value in the context?

Answer (score 2):

During the `create` or `write` of an `account.move` with only `invoice_line_ids` set and not `line_ids`, the [_move_autocomplete_invoice_lines_create](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L1677) or [_move_autocomplete_invoice_lines_write](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L1702) method is called to auto compute accounting lines of the invoice. In that case, accounts will be retrieved and taxes, cash rounding, and payment terms will be computed. In the end, the values will contain all accounting lines in `line_ids` and the moves should be balanced.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Odoo 13 dated December 10, 2021.

Edit file: /path_of_odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py

Example:
vim /odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py

Modify function named _check_balanced and comment line 1582 and add new line whit return

Example:

############################### Before ##################################
[image]

############################### A F T E R ###############################

[image]